# Описание входных параметров HoughCircles()

Tags: c#, opencv

Пытаюсь приспособить метод HoughCircles() не для поиска кругов, а для пикселей нужного мне цвета на картинке. Не могу понять, за что отвечают входные параметры метода cannyThreshold, accumulatorThreshold и dp:

*cannyThreshold - The higher threshold of the two passed to Canny edge detector (the lower one will be twice smaller).

*accumulatorThreshold - Accumulator threshold at the center detection stage. The smaller it is, the more false circles may be detected. Circles, corresponding to the larger accumulator values, will be returned first

*dp - esolution of the accumulator used to detect centers of the circles. For example, if it is 1, the accumulator will have the same resolution as the input image, if it is 2 - accumulator will have twice smaller width and height, etc

Прошу перевести данную информацию из метаданных.

Comment: А про пикселы нужного цвета я упустил - разве для этого нужна функция обнаружения окружностей?

Comment: @MBo я бы с радостью узнал бы как можно иначе решить задачу. Факт в том - что найти пиксели нужного цвета я могу и с помощью HoughCircles(). Если предложите другое решение - буду крайне признателен

Comment: Чтобы  узнать цвет пиксела, нужно просто к нему обратиться - как в шарпе, я не знаю - через `mat.at(x,y)` ? Но, вероятно, задача несколько посложнее?

Comment: @MBo для поиска цвета действительно можно использовать GetPixel, и не нужно даже компьютерное зрение. Но скорость работы программы катастрофически низкая и потому данный подход не приемлем.

Comment: Может быть, стоит описать проблему в отдельном вопросе? Потому что поиск пиксела определённого цвета - это одна из самых простых и быстрых задач, и требует времени несравнимо меньше, чем Хаф.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы правильно настраивать эти параметры, нужно приобрести некоторый опыт в обработке изображений.

Первый параметр - значение, используемое в процедуре выделения связных границ Кэнни. Точки со значениями перепадов (градиента) выше этой границы считаются сильными и безусловно включаются в результат, точки с градиентами менее половина этой границы - считаются слабыми, и безусловно исключаются, а часть промежуточных включается по определённым правилам. В общем, чем больше этот параметр, тем меньше шума попадёт в результат, но и могут не слишком яркие границы кругов потеряться.

Третий параметр - разрешение аккумулятора, в который будут складываться результаты преобразования Хафа. Это решётка, на которой помечаются узлы, к которым может относиться каждая выделенная на первом этапе точка. Чем мельче ячейки - тем теоретически точнее определение координат, однако квадратично растёт размер памяти и хуже того - в узлы попадает слишком мало пометок (голосов), и становится трудно выделить узлы с наибольшим количеством голосов (потенциальные центры окружностей)

А вот второй параметр - как раз относится к количеству голосов, выше которого узел аккумулятора может считаться  описывающим центр окружности